# Is the rfc-info "help: ways_to_get_rfcs" dead?

Tags: tcp, rfc

I was just reading "TCP/IP Illustrated" and found that one of the ways to find all sources of RFCs is to send the following email:

```
To: rfc-info@ISI.EDU
Subject: getting rfcs

help: ways_to_get_rfcs
```

Tried it for fun -- how could I not when it's such a interesting/intriguing way of getting info? I mean, would you even think of sending an email to some remote address to get the ways to get rfcs? -- and got "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently". I'm pretty sure it's long dead, but do you know when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to figure it out is to look through the old RFCs... they're generally sequential in both numbering and dates (though there is admittedly some variation).

[RFC2700 - Pub Aug 2000](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2700.txt) Contains a reference to rfc-info@ISI.EDU

[RFC2800 - Pub May 2001](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2800.txt) Does not...

So without getting more granular, it was between August 2000 and May 2001.

HTH,
\mike